# How to create and send html file to client in nodeJS from backend(express)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, backend, react-fullstack

Im trying to create a file from a string that contains html content for example:

const html = "`<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <p>example</p> </body> </html>`";

Now how would you create a read stream and pipe it to the response without creating the file locally?

Comment: I don't understand why not creating the HTML locally, but anyway maybe this NPM package will be what you need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express you can do the following

```
// as string (for short strings)
router.get('/my-html', function (req, res) {
  const html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <p>example</p> </body> </html>";
  
  res.type('html');
  res.send(html);
})
```

Or

```js
// as stream (for large strings)
router.get('/my-html', function (req, res) {
  const html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <p>example</p> </body> </html>";
  const readStream = Readable.from(html)
  
  res.type('html');
  readStream.pipe(res);
})
```